# Python - How does the following expression get evaluated?

Tags: python, lexical-analysis

```
a=5;b=10;a----------------++++++++++++++++++b
# Output: 15
```

The above is the output of a python script.
Could you please explain how it works? I was quite surprised that it works and gives an answer!!

However a similar such expression doesn't work in Java,C,C++
For instance:

```
 a=10;    
 b=5;
 System.out.println(a---b);//error!!
 cout<<a---b;//error
 printf("%d\n",a---b);//error
```

Does this have something to do with the compiler - lexical analyser/syntactical analyser?
I understand there is a "leftmost, eager and greedy" approach taken by compilers, but I dont exactly understand how that works in this case.

Comment: but `a---b` works and it´s similar aswell

Comment: In e.g. Java, what would `a--b` mean? Would it mean `a --b`? `a-- b`? `a - -b`? It will assume it's one of the first two cases, and neither of those are valid.

Comment: Which of those three other langauges do you want an answer for? In C the answer is "it is a syntax error". Or are you asking a Python question?

Comment: The first `-` is subtraction, the last `+` is a unary operator operating on `b` and the rest are unary operators operating on the result of the previously evaluated one. It's valid but perverse code in Python. Other languages do their own thing.

Comment: Answer: because they are different languages and they follow different syntax. Period.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Sure, "why doesn't this work in other languages" isn't a great question, but "how does this get evaluated?" is a perfectly acceptable one.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the poster should have sat down at the Python interpreter and worked it out by typing `0-1`, `0--1`, `0+-1`, `0+-+++1` etc.

Comment: Oh, and I was curious enough myself to find out for myself what would happen were b a string. (I guessed error, and was right).

Comment: Make sure to always include 4 different language tags in your questions, to attract 4 times more down votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, that's

```
a - ---------------++++++++++++++++++b
```

that is, subtracting `---------------++++++++++++++++++b` from `a`.

The prefix `-`, negation, changes the sign of a number, the prefix `+` does nothing.
Example:

```
>>> -+2
-2
>>> +-2
-2
>>> --2
2
```

Since there are 15 negations, `a - ---------------++++++++++++++++++b` is equivalent to `a - -b`, which is `a + b`.

Java, C, and C++ have prefix and postfix `--` and `++` (decrement and increment) operators, and by the "maximal munch rule", your expression would read as

```
(((((((((((((((((a--)--)--)--)--)--)--)--)++)++)++)++)++)++)++)++)++) b
```

which, even if those operations on `a` were legal, would be as much nonsense as `a b` is.
(Note that `a---b` is valid; it means `a-- - b`.)

Details about the workings of the increment and decrement operators can be found in any suitable book.

Comment: Thanks! This sure did help.